# How to replace Fixed top navigation with hamburger button?

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, web-frontend

I am trying to use the [Scrolling Nav](http://blackrockdigital.github.io/startbootstrap-scrolling-nav/) template to create a website. On the mobile version, it provides me with a fixed top navigation bar with a hamburger button. How can I go about altering the template to replace the hamburger button?

Comment: Made question a little clearer hopefully

Answer (score 1):

change display to inline-block or table-cell

Answer (score 0):

https://css-tricks.com/three-line-menu-navicon/
Try doing something like this.